# Windows Applications and CLR

Tags: windows, forms, menu, clr

What is this Common Language Runtime that I've been hearing about?

I've recently started a project to create my own, small, personal windows application.  I've used DirectX for drawing in the window and such before, for games and whatnot, however this time, I wanted to make it a more standard style application, with menus, and selectable text, and right clicking.

I've searched, but I found no information on how to actually write code for such things, I've only found things telling me to use the drag-and-drop form interface, for windows.

Anyways, I've found that using the forms, actually lets me see the code behind it, too, so I guess I could learn that way....

...but its forcing me to compile using CLR.  Why? What is CLR?  Can I not create this style of windows application without it?

-Stefan

Comment: Your question is a little unclear but it sounds as though you want to write a GUI app without .net. You can do that using Win32/MFC/VCL/WTL/Qt etc. etc. As for what CLR is, yry websearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLR is the runtime for the .Net framework.
You can only run .Net code on the CLR.

Since WinForms is a .Net library, you can only use WinForms in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

CLR (Common Language Runtime) is a Virtual Machine. Whenever you compile your .Net programs they are converted into an intermediate language whereas a regular compiler would compile to native code of the target platform. Now whenever there is a CLR implementation available for an OS your program will run on that OS. This is how your .Net programs are portable! Read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere